# How to get the object name from within the class?

Tags: python, class, object

I've got a simple class from which I create two objects. I now want to print the name of the object from within the class. So something like this:

```
class Example:
    def printSelf(self):
        print self

object1 = Example()
object2 = Example()

object1.printSelf()
object2.printSelf()
```

I need this to print:

```
object1
object2
```

Unfortunately this just prints `<myModule.Example instance at 0xb67e77cc>`

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: By name of the object, do you mean - name of the reference (object1, object2, ...)??

Comment: Yes indeed. Excuse me for not being explicit on this, I'll edit my question on that.

Comment: See my original post here: stackoverflow.com/a/59364138/5088165

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object1` is just an identifier(or variable) pointing to an instance object, objects don't have names.

```
>>> class A:
...     def foo(self):
...         print self
...         
>>> a = A()
>>> b = a
>>> c = b     
>>> a,b,c    #all of them point to the same instance object
(<__main__.A instance at 0xb61ee8ec>, <__main__.A instance at 0xb61ee8ec>, <__main__.A instance at 0xb61ee8ec>)
```

`a`,`b`,`c` are simply references that allow us to access a same object, when an object has **0** references it is automatically garbage collected.

A quick hack will be to pass the name when creating the instance:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...         
>>> a = A('a')
>>> a.name
'a'
>>> foo = A('foo')
>>> foo.name
'foo'
>>> bar = foo # additional references to an object will still return the original name
>>> bar.name
'foo'
```

Comment: Does this mean that what I am trying to do is impossible?

Comment: @kramer65 yes, you can't get a variable name in python. They are just references to access an object.

Comment: I think you mean objects don't have names; a variable consists of a name and a value (although it is more correct to say that Python has identifiers which are bound to objects than to say it has variables).

Comment: Alright. That's a pity. I just have two objects created from the same class. In one of them something seems to go wrong. So to debug I want to print some info from one of the objects, but not from the other one. That's why I wanted to do an if self == 'someObject': print 'someinfo'. But in that case I'll have to find a different solution. Thanks!

Comment: @kramer65 I've added a simple workaround solution.

Comment: @kramer65 The solution to your problem is to use a debugger, not gum up your code

Answer (score 4):

The object does not have a "name". A variable which refers to the object is not a "name" of the object. The object cannot know about any of the variables which refer to it, not least because variables are not a first-class subject of the language.

If you wish to alter the way that object prints, override either `__repr__` or `__unicode__`.

If this is for debugging purposes, use a debugger. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to do this is something along these lines:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

object1 = Example('object1')
object2 = Example('object2')

print object1
print object2
```

Prints:

```
object1
object2
```

However, there is no guarantee that this object remains bound to the original name:

```
object1 = Example('object1')
object2 = object1

print object1
print object2
```

Prints `object1`, as expected, twice. If you want to see things under the hood -- use a debugger.

Comment: Don't you need to print object1.name and object2.name!? EDIT: Didn't notice the \_\_str\_\_ dunder, not sure when that gets invoked though.